# Google Fonts on Mobile vs Desktop

Tags: css, media-queries, google-fonts

I'm using the Merriweather font for my webapp by importing it like below.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300i">`

This works fine on desktop browsers but on mobile, it falls back to the default font. If I replace the line to import `300` instead of `300i`, everything seems to work fine.

Would anyone know how can I still make use of the `300i` font on desktops and fall back to `300` on mobile?

Comment: Have you tried combining those two together in one link like: [link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300i|Merriweather:300) or [link](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300|Merriweather:300i). I'm not really sure what will happen, but it's worth a try i guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at any css you might have implemented, the easiest way to change fronts between web and mobile is to use media queries.

Since you want to use both the 300 and 300i, import

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300,300i"    rel="stylesheet">
```

Set your normal default text to

```
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
```

For mobile use the media queries:

```
@media all and (max-width: 991px) or (max-width: 768px) or (max-width: 480px) {
* these are the three popular mobile queries *
}
```

Inside of the media query you can set the text:

```
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import both fonts into your main stylesheet.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Merriweather:300i;
    src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300i);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Merriweather:300;
    src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:300i);
}
```

(You might need to put the actual location of the `.woff` file in the `src:` property.)

Then use [specific media queries for mobile and desktop](https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)

```
/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  * {
      font-family: Merriweather:300i
   }

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {     

  * {
      font-family: Merriweather:300
   }

}
```